# How to embed the camera screen in the part of the main form?

Tags: codenameone

I've some trouble regarding camera feature in codenameone.
I can use camera as full screen as follow:

```
com.codename1.capture.Capture.capturePhoto();
```

This opens full camera screen, however, I want it to be embedded in special part(e.g. square) of the main form.

I've heard native interface is needed for this. But I couldn't know the detail source code.
Is there any way to do this or to get any source code?

(PS: I'm looking for the solution for iOS/Android.)

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible with a new cn1lib: https://github.com/codenameone/CameraKitCodenameOne

Original answer below:

Codename One didn't support z-ordering of peer components until recently so this was not reasonably possible until a couple of months ago when we [introduced that feature](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/z-order-peers-in-ios-javascript.html).

This is now available in all supported Codename One platforms and thus it should be possible to create a cn1lib that will allow you to do just that.

We hope to build such a cn1lib ourselves but with our current workload I'm not sure when we'll get around to do it.